# htaccess 301 redirect subdirectory one level deeper - why is this not working?

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect

it is probably a stupid question, but I have real troubles figuring out, how to redirect

/products to /products/item

It is a simple redirect, no regex needed. The toplevel site /products should just always redirect to /products/item

I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RedirectMatch 301 /products(.*) /products/item/$1
</IfModule>
```

I receive the error, that the webserver is redirecting in an infinite loop. That might be because of the rest of the htaccess file. Which looks like that:

```
# Custom Rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RedirectMatch 301 /products(.*) /products/item/$1
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

But the strangest thing: When I load the page, I get the error. When I then hit reload, it works???

Thanks for your help!
ole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *just* want to redirect `/products` to `/products/item`, this should work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/?$ /products/item
```

The `^` and `$` characters anchor the regular expression to the beginning and end of the path, so that it won't match `/foo/products` or `/products/bar`.  The `/?` allows it to match both `/products` and `/products/`; you can remove it if you don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

The `(.*)` after products is what's causing the loop. It redirects
`/products/something` to `/products/item/something`, but then that has to be redirected to `/products/item/item/something` etc.

You need to exclude item so this may work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /products/(?!^item)(.*) /products/item/$1
```

This means redirect `/products/something` except something beginning `/products/item`.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to redirect /products/something, I want to redirect /products/ one level deeper to /products/item . Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I thought that because you had the (.*) and the $1 in your file. That's what they are there for. In that case Ilmari's answer is what you need.